# Webpack and version numbers in output file

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack to build my react application. I just want to know is there are way of generating html having script tab with version number in file name like 
.

I have tried to explore the HtmlWebpackPlugin but found nothing. Can anyone give me a direction whether there is a plugin available to do this or I have to write my own script.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Fulfilling *[@Manis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416579/#43986279)* I want to provide more complete instructions on this solution.

It can be achieved by [`output.filename` substitutions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output#output-filename) settings.

```js
{
    entry: ['./your/entry.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js', // Line of interest
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    /* ... */
}
```

> The `[contenthash]` substitution will add a unique hash based on the content of an asset. When the asset's content changes, `[contenthash]` will change as well.

*More options and examples **[here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename)**.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `[hash]` in the name of your output files. [Look here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) for more details.

> P.S.: Your `index.html` should have correct file name as far as I'm experiencing in my project

Answer (score 1):

If the question here is how to use the version from your `package.json`, I had the same problem and solved it by:

add this to your webpack.config.js

```
var PACKAGE = require('./package.json');
var version = PACKAGE.version;
```

Then you can append the version to your file:

```
  output: {
    ...
    filename: `myLibrary-${version}.js`
    ...
  }
```